# Why won't tomcat6 not bind to port 80?

Tags: tomcat6

I'm aware of the implications of running tomcat on port 80, but I'm after a quick solution. I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://java-notes.com/index.php/installing-tomcat-with-http-port-80-on-linux). I've followed the tutorial with two changes:

- tomcat6 is user name tomcat is run as
- The location of tomcat conf file: `/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh`

But I'm still getting permissions errors. Java is saying its unable to bind to port 80. What else should i be doing? What other information should i provide for people to debug?
Just to confirm, there's nothing else running on port 80

Comment: and you are doing this with root privileges?

Comment: how do you mean? im logged in as root when configuring the server?

Comment: No, when starting the server. In the tutorial it is this part: sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart

Comment: yes, im logged in as root when i restart the server (so i dont need the sudo part)

Answer (score 6):

You can change AUTOBIND property of `/etc/default/tomcat6` to "yes" as follows:

```
AUTHBIND=yes
```

Restart your tomcat and that will enable you to use available privileged port (1-1023).

Comment: I done that thing as well. Still not getting. @richzilla : if your code is working please let me know and mark this one as verified so that we can discuss further on this answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different  ways of doing this without actually touching the tomcat config.

You can make an iptables script that redirects traffic from port 80 to port 8080 (then you dont need to fiddle around with tomcat settings)

for iptables

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80`
would do the trick!  (make a script so its done automatically on uppstart

or you can create a Apache reverse proxy that actually proxies the connections to your tomcatserver through it (this is good since it can actually cache request and speed up connections for you)

Comment: Shouldn't `8080` and `80` port should be switched in the provided script? i.e. `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

Answer (score 0):

In the Tomcat HTTP connector, make sure your connector on port 80 is binding to ALL interfaces,  or  0.0.0.0  ,  rather than just 127.1  .   That might explain why your not able to connect with a url such as  http://10.0.0.2:80   but  you can with  http://127.1:80

Answer (score 0):

Start tomcat services using authbind this will allow user to start ports less than 1024 we do not need to redirect or iptables.

> apt-get install authbind -y

To install Authbind software

> chmod -R 755 /etc/authbind

group should be user group.

> chown -Rh root:group /etc/authbind

After that run the below commands

> cd /etc/authbind/byuid

As an example lets imagne user id is 2000 you can use your user id number

> echo '0.0.0.0/0:1,1023' > 2000

That file should be own by user and group.

chown : 2000

chmod 700 2000

Add the below line in tomcat startup file $CATALINA_BASE/startup.sh

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

For Starting tomcat using Authbind service startup.sh

Comment the below line

```
#$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

Add This End as the end of the file

```
AUTHBIND_COMMAND="/usr/bin/authbind --deep /bin/bash -c " 

$AUTHBIND_COMMAND $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

now you should be able to start tomcat services as user with less that 1024 ports.